# Creating parent child label columns in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, parent-child, calculated-columns, ssrs-tablix, ssms-2017

I have a stored procedure and an ssrs report that takes work orders of a certain category (user entered parameter, ex. A,B) and then selects other work orders of the unselected categories (C,D) that are within a user entered buffer distance (parameter). The listing that the report generates contains a Primary Work Order Id field (Primary WOID) and a Buffer Work Order Id field (Buffer WOID).  I need to create a single column that indicates the parent/child (Primary/Buffer) relationship as well as well as the grouping of the records. The screenshot below is an example of what I would want the new column to look like. 
[desired column in listing report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoqjC.png). I'm using Report Builder 3.0 and SSMS v17.2 .

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have a sort order your created key, like you want to do it, could be different every time. Or if you load more or less data you get the same problem.

You should just concatenate the fields and thus creating your key. For example if you concatenate the columns `Primary WOID, Buffer WOID, Priority Category`:

```
=Fields!PrimaryWOID.Value & Fields!BufferWOID.Value & Priority Category
```

Result:

```
8944925B
89449256570374C
89449258145995C
8944920B
...
```